# Use multiple environment files

Tags: angular, angular7

On an Angular 7 application I have the following `environment.prod.ts` file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiBaseUri: 'https://api.xyz.com'
};
```

I need to publish the application in 2 different machines.

And I need, for each one, two configurations: Production and Staging.

So I need to have something like the following environment files:

```
environment.prod.machine-1.ts
environment.prod.machine-2.ts

environment.staging.machine-1.ts
environment.staging.machine-2.ts
```

How should I defined these environment files?

And how to build the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to build angular project with different environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604297/how-to-build-angular-project-with-different-environment)

Answer (score 2):

In `angular.json`, under `"projects.<your project name>.architect.build.configurations"` you can define each type of configuration per machine. Under each configuration define `fileReplacements`, like so:

```
"projects": {
  "<your project name>": {
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "configurations": {
          "machine-1.production": {
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.machine-1.ts"
              }
            ]
          },
          "machine-1.staging": {
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.machine-1.ts"
              }
            ]
          },
          // same for machine 2, etc...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, to build your project using that environment, run

```sh
ng build --configuration=machine-2.staging
```

(or whichever other environment you want).

Comment: I see. One thing that confuses me is the use of "production: true / false" on the environment files. What does it do?

Comment: @MiguelMoura There's no such `"production"` property defined under `"configurations.<your configuration>"` according to the `angular.json` schema. What do you mean exactly? Are you referencing the `--prod` argument for `ng build`? If so, it's just a shortcut of `--configuration=production`, so if you have no configuration named `"production"` under `"projects.<your project name>.architect.build.configurations"`, running `ng build --prod` won't work.